# Calling cm.cublas_shutdown() in CUDAMat always raises exceptions

Tags: python, gpu

I tried running the example scripts `examples/nn_cudamat.py` and `examples/rbm_cudamat.py.py` included with the latest version of CUDAMat which wraps CUDA's cublas library and provides a Python matrix class for gpu computing.

Both examples run fine but finish with multiple exceptions like this example:

```
Exception cudamat.CUDAMatException: CUDAMatException('CUBLAS error.',) in <bound method CUDAMatrix.__del__ of <cudamat.CUDAMatrix object at 0xf27290>> ignored
```

There were no failures running the nose tests after installation.

I am not sure what exactly is causing the error but it seems to occur anytime `cm.cublas_shutdown()` is called at the end of a script where a `cm.CUDAMatrix` object was created.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cudamat as cm
    cm.cublas_init()
    cm.cublas_shutdown()
```

exits fine but:

```
import numpy as np
import cudamat as cm
    cm.cublas_init()
    a = cm.CUDAMatrix(np.random.rand(5, 5))
    print a.asarray()
    cm.cublas_shutdown()
```

runs fine but gives the exception at the end.

CUDAMatrix.**del** frees the device memory corresponding the the matrix like this:

```
extern int free_device_memory(cudamat* mat) {
    if (mat->owns_data && mat->on_device) {
        cublasStatus stat;

        stat = cublasFree(mat->data_device);
        mat->on_device = 0;

        if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS || check_cublas_error())
            return CUBLAS_ERROR;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

and cm.cublas_shutdown() does the following:

```
extern int cublas_shutdown() {
    cublasShutdown();
    cudaThreadExit();
    return 0;
}
```

Someone else has the same problem and made an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/cudamat/issues/detail?id=12) on the CUDAMat page a while back but there hasn't been any solution.

So why is this happening?

Some info:
Latest version of CUDAMat (docs say 0.3)
Python 2.6.6
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Cuda Toolkit 5.0

Comment: I am getting the same error here! Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I think it is caused by Python's garbage collection trying to free the CUDA memory by calling the .__del__ method of the CUDAMatrix class AFTER the cublas context has been shutdown. When I manually delete each CUDAMatrix object, `del matrix` for example, before the cublas.shutdown call, then there is no error message.

Comment: My problem was simpler. The cudamat was not loaded right, so I just replaced the cudamat code with the original code and everything worked fine.

Comment: Removing the `cudaThreadExit()` in cudamat.cu line 47 solves the problem. They planned to release that in Release 0.4 which never saw daylight. https://github.com/cudamat/cudamat/issues/19